# Windows Store App: Should I use ListBox or ListView?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a question about Windows Store Apps:

what is the difference between the:

- `ListBox`
- `ListView`

i want to have a list with different `TextBlocks`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more Windows-8 App style control is the `ListView`.  It has built-in functionality for things like scrolling.  The `ListBox` does basically the same things except it doesn't have the nice scrolling functionality.

See [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/WinAZ/archive/2012/02/13/windows-8-listbox-2-listview.aspx) for a more in-depth treatment.